# Searching for a particular line of text in a text file

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am having issues with my synonym map. I want to be able to search a text file for a keyword or a related word in the textfile then outputting the found sentence. so  my program searches for the answers to questions based  on the keyword or sunonym. the way my program works is by  searching a text file for a keyword in the question and then outputting the answer to the question which is the next line after then question in the text file. When i search for the main keyword in a question the program works. But when i try to ask a question with the related word the program does not recognize the input. So for example if i enter "how is the major?" the answer to that question is on the next line which is "the major is difficult" but if i enter "how is the focus" the program does not recognize the related word *focus* Can someone help me find the issue which lies in searching for a related word also. Here is my text file

```
 what is the textbook name?
 the textbook name is Java
 how is the major?
 the major is difficult
 how much did the shoes cost?
 the shoes cost two dollars
 how is the major when cramer took it?
 when cramer took it, it was okay
 how is the major when jar took it?
 jar said it was fine
 what is the color of my bag?
 the color of my bag is blue
```

and here is my code

```
 public static class DicEntry {
    String key;
    String[] syns;
    Pattern pattern;

    public DicEntry(String key, String... syns) {
        this.key = key;
        this.syns = syns;
        pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(?:"
                + Stream.concat(Stream.of(key), Stream.of(syns))
                        .map(x -> "\\b" + Pattern.quote(x) + "\\b")
                        .collect(Collectors.joining("|")) + ").*");
    }
}



public static void parseFile(String s) throws IOException {

    List<DicEntry> synonymMap = populateSynonymMap(); // populate the map

    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    Scanner forget = new Scanner(System.in);

    int flag_found = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();

        for (DicEntry entry : synonymMap) { // iterate over each word of the
                                            // sentence.

            if (entry.pattern.matcher(s).matches()) {

                if (lineFromFile.contains(entry.key)) {

                    //String bat = entry.key;
                    if(lineFromFile.contains(s))      {
                    String temp = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(temp);



                }
            }
        }
    }
    }


}


private static List<DicEntry> populateSynonymMap() {
    List<DicEntry> responses = new ArrayList<>();
    responses.add(new DicEntry("bag", "purse", "black"));
    responses.add(new DicEntry("shoe", "heels", "gas"));
    responses.add(new DicEntry("major", "discipline", "focus", "study"));

    return responses;
}

public static void getinput() throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    /* End Initialization */
    System.out.println("Welcome ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    parseFile(input);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {
    /* Initialization */
    getinput();

}

}
```

Comment: Please try to remove any unnecessary parts from your code (e.g. asking and writing answers to questions not found in the text file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that after you pass

```
if (lineFromFile.contains(entry.key))
```

in your `parseFile(String s)` method, you would want to know if your user entered input contains any of the `entry.syns` and replace the synonym with the key

```
// This is case sensitive
boolean synonymFound = false;
for (String synonym : entry.syns) {
    if (s.contains(synonym)) {
        s = s.replace(synonym, entry.key)
        break;
    }
}
```

Since you want to stop searching once you find a match (exact or synonym match), you'll want to have a `return` statement to kick out of the method or use a flag to kick out of the `while (scanner.hasNextLine())`

```
if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
    String temp = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(temp);

    flag_found = 1;

    System.out
            .println(" Would you like to update this information ? ");
    String yellow = forget.nextLine();
    if (yellow.equals("yes")) {
        // String black = scanner.nextLine();
        removedata(temp);
    } else if (yellow.equals("no")) {

        System.out.println("Have a good day");
        // break;
    }

    // Add return statment to end the search
    return;
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your post. But if i ask *how is the focus?* the answer should only be *the major is difficult* not every single instance where the word major is found. Understand? In addition, if i ask "how was the focus when cramer took it" the output should only be *when cramer took it, it was okay*

Comment: You the truth mate. Thanks alot